# Is there anything using command blocks to check if an entity is greater than certain ranges of a command block?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I was wanting to run a command based off of when a player gets out of the range of a command block, or if they are within two ranges. For example, like [this](https://jonah.is-a-virg.in/Mxb0Up.png) where when the player gets inside of the red range that then the player gets a command run on them. Is there any way to do this as easily as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newer versions of minecraft you can use `/execute as @a[distance=x..y] run <command>`

x is the distance in blocks from which to start targeting

y is the furthest it will target players in blocks

The two `..` are important

`Example: /execute as @a[distance=10..15] run effect @s give minecraft:levitation 1 1 true`

Answer (score 0):

`/execute as @a[r=your_range] run (your command)`
r is the radius around the command block